# How to properly handle socket exception

Tags: python, sockets

In my Python program I have a socket listening to incoming connections and when I run `nmap` on it, it closes abruptly as it resets the connection when scanning the port.

I tried putting an `except: pass` block on the end of my code, along with the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        listen()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

But upon receiving the connection reset, it doesn't pass. It just closes the program without printing anything.
How might I solve this?
The server-side code responsible for receiving and next to it, the handling of info. Should I put something after the `while` block, or just an `except`?

```
connection.listen(10)
while True:
    current_connection, address = connection.accept()
    current_connection.send('Input:')
    while True:
        data = current_connection.recv(2048)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 41, in <module>
    listen()
  File "server.py", line 12, in listen
    current_connection.send('Input:')
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is structured, if you put an `except: pass` at the top-level, then when the exception occurs, it's only trapped at the top level and there's nothing in your code to cause it go back into your `listen`..`accept` code. You should instead trap the exception at the right spot in the code so that your code continues the outer `while True` loop.

In general. it's a good idea to place all socket operations that might ordinarily fail inside a try-except block. It's considered bad practice in python to have a bare `except` though -- as a bare `except` tends to hide errors in your code that should not be hidden. Hence, you'll typically do something like this:

```
connection.listen(10)
while True:
    current_connection, address = connection.accept()
    try:
        current_connection.sendall('Input:')
        while True:
            data = current_connection.recv(2048)
            if data == '':
                break          # End of file (peer socket was closed)
    except socket.error as sockerr:
        print("Socket exception on send/recv", sockerr)
    current_connection.close()
```

Also, note that I replaced `send` with `sendall`. This ensures that the entire string will get sent. (With `send`, it's valid in some circumstances for fewer bytes to be sent than the entire string.)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I will keep that in mind when handling exceptions in the future.